# IsPrime Method has dead code and doesn't return int

Tags: java

I want to create a java method that checks if the int number that the user inputs is prime or not. However, I am getting "dead code" and "this method must return a result of type int". Any help guys?

```
  public static int isPrime(int first)
  {

    for (int i = first - 1; i > 1; i--)

      if (first%i == 0){
      int prime = 1;
      return prime;
    }

    else{
      int notPrime = 0;
      return notPrime;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens if `i` is 1 or less. Hint: the for loop condition is false from the start

Comment: You should really be using braces with your `for` loop and also proper indentation. I think that would have made it less confusing for you. It is true what Dunes said: both your `return` statements are placed within your for loop, but what happens if the code never enters the loop because of its initial condition?

Comment: @Carcigenicate The for loop without braces is actually valid syntax. It will just loop over the following statement, in this case the if-else.  The dead code here is the i-- because the loop will execute at most once.  The error is because the for loop may not execute at all, so there needs to be a return after the loop.

Comment: I understand where the problem with my code lies. Firstly, I have formatted everything, then, I have  made my condition so that it runs the first time; and then again if it allows. Lastly, I have put 1 return statement outside of the loop. Now, it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers are prime if the only divisors they have are 1 and itself. Trivially, we can check every integer from 1 to itself (exclusive) and test whether it divides evenly.

For example, one might be tempted to run this algorithm:

```
//checks whether an int is prime or not.
 boolean isPrime(int n) {
     for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
         if(n%i==0)
             return false;
     }
     return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After copy and pasting this into an editor, it's clear that `i--` is the part that causes the dead code warning to appear. The reason for this is because your `for` loop will return during its first iteration either way, and the part of your code `i--` will never be executed (dead code).

Other than that there are a couple other issues in your code mentioned in other answers & comments.

Answer (score 0):

Move your return statement outside of the for loop.

Since you're returning in the loop in both the if and the else your loop will only ever run once.

Edit: you'll also have to track prime differently.

```
public static int isPrime(int first)
  {

    for (int i = first - 1; i > 1; i--) {

       if (first%i == 0){
          return 1;
        }
    }


    return 0;


}
```

Sorry for formatting im on my phone

Answer (score -1):

```
 int isPrime(int n) {
   for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
       if(n%i==0)
          return 1;
      }
     return 0;  
   }
```

the program returns 1 if prime 0 otherwise

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions (in fact, it's not very valuable, because it's one of the slowest prime tests possible).  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.